# Geoserver, how many concurrent users

Tags: tomcat, glassfish, geoserver

I've been searching quite a lot but haven't found a clear rule of thumb for how many concurrent users Geoserver can handle, either in Tomcat or Glassfish containers.

Let's say that at peak times there might be around 400 concurrent users, and the requirement for average response time for a single tile (WMS) should be less than a second. Is this going to require a clustered solution with two or even more virtual machines running Geoserver?

Any kind of experiences would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on the type of WMS queries made. You write 'single tile' so I assume 256x256 pixels. Can they be cached?

It also depends on the datasource (vector/raster, files/database), complexity of styling, available memory and the nature of the application. If it's 400 users zooming and panning at the same time or 400 users of your app it's probably a big difference.

Comment: As koordo said this depepnds on many factors:

- size, type and level of processing of your data
- which type of interaction they are making
- styles
- speed of the back-end  in case the data in on a DBMS and # of connections available (you need ideally 400 DB connections at hand to handle 400 tile requests for data in a db if you have no caching in between
- HW specs

I would advice to have a look at the GeoServer on steroid tracks from the foss4g workshops. Here is a starting point http://goo.gl/74XUPq